# Fetch profile details from LinkedIn without requiring User Authentication

Tags: linkedin-api

I am currently working on an in-house application for my company, where I need to fetch various LinkedIn member details such as their name, profile picture, number of connections, and recent activity for verification purposes without requiring User Authentication for each profile.

After discussion with LinkedIn team on chat and researching on Stack Overflow, I found that the conventional way to access this information is by becoming a LinkedIn partner, a process that reportedly takes 90 days. Unfortunately, this timeline is too long for our application's requirements. Hence, I am seeking advice on any alternative methods or workarounds to expedite this process and obtain the required member details from LinkedIn without being a partner. Also, if there are any ways to expedite the LinkedIn partner application process, it will be great. Any insights or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Comment: In the list of data you would like to get from the site there is something, which I guess, can be private and can require to have some kind of connection to the account of the user observed. Also, accessing the data the company provide only for custom group of users (specific scope, role) may violate their policies and lead to ban or something worse.